# Emitting to specific room of socket.io 1.X namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

- I've implemented a number of socket.io namespaces that a user can connect to based on the page they are on.
- Emitting data to a particular namespace:room combination seems to require excess boilerplate.
- This is how I'm currently setting up the namespace and emitting events to sockets in a given room:

---

1) Setting up the namespace

```
let newsNs = io.of('/news');
newsNs.on(CONNECTION, socket => {
    socket.join('political');
});
```

2) Emitting an event to sockets in the `/news` namespace and `political` room:

```
newsNs.in('political').clients((err, clients) => {
    clients.forEach(c => newsNs.connected[c].emit(EVENT, 'data'));
})
```

---

Is there a cleaner and more concise way to emit to all sockets in a namespace:room combination without first iterating over each client and then deriving the sockets from someNs.connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `newsNs.to('political').emit(payload)` should suffice.

Check out http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#joining-and-leaving as an example.

Comment: Wow, this *does* work.  I tried this last night, but when it didn't work I started searching for other solutions.  Looks like I had been leaving the room after I had joined it.  My connection handler removes the socket from all other rooms before connecting to the new one, and with 'room.leave' being asynchronous, I had forgot to check that the new room isn't also removed.

Comment: Ah yes, gotta love race conditions. Glad you figured it out!